# How to make ffmeg automatically overwrite a file with the same name?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a script that downloads audio and video from a youtube link,
then ffmpeg merges them together — but if I want to merge again, it will output a file with the same name and it will ask me in the terminal:

[image]

How can I make it so it automatically overwrite?

Comment: `ffmpeg` accepts an argument to allow overwriting, so you wll need to pass that when your script runs it. We can't tell you how to do that without seeing your code, but you haven't included any in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use command ffmpeg, according to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) you should add -y flag before the name of output file.